How to best size Variable Frequency Drive (VFD) to motor
I have a specific application (3 HP-2.2 kW, 220 V 3PH/9.5 A, 3000 rpm induction motor from an old woodworking combination machine) I would like to use a Variable Frequency Drive for.
Are there specific guidelines for matching a given VFD to a motor, other than obviously the voltage? I see VFDs tend to be rated for specific power and current. If, say, a motor is 2.2 kW, should a 2.2 kW VFD be used? Or the next step-up in power (e.g., 3 kW)?

This page also has some useful information related to my application (VFD in woodworking machine): http://sawdust.online.fr/Power/VariableFrequency/en_vfd.php

The main factor in sizing drives is the mechanical load.
Standard pumps and fans (centrifugal, quadratic torque) normally will run below rated power, so you can match the drive size to motor power. Some applications as conveyor belts have constant torque behaviour; also in high mechanical inertia, or when often overload is foreseen, you increase the size of the drive one or more step up. The thermal inertia of semiconductors is much lower than a motor, so you cannot overload the drive as the motor can do. As example, in metal industry rolling is usual to use drives from 150 to 200 % of motor power.
Some manufacturers offer app tools for sizing. You can define the mechanical torque and speed cycles of the load, and recommends you the drive from their catalogue.
Another factor in air cooled drives is altitude over 1000 m, the lower density will not cool properly and oversizing is mandatory.

It depends on usage and your needs for RPM load regulation.
A startup without VFD limits can be 5x the rated power, but with controlled acceleration power can be limited to <100% by trial and error. Similarly, if power is limited by current, and surge loads exceed that limit, then the voltage will drop rapidly and RPM slip will increase the same. If the load is not removed quickly, the motor may stall.

Thank you. I'm not a native speaker, but to make sure I understand it, should the second sentence not rather read as follows (or similarly)?:  A startup without VFD limits can be 5x the rated power but with controlled acceleration, power can be limited to <100% by trial and error.

Yes that is ok too. I meant a motor and a switch with start/ run caps and no VFD
